# support libraries must use the exact same version specification

Tags: android, android-support-library

I have tried running my app using a specific activity, and I a continuous crash is taking place.

I have pinpointed an error that is to do with the appcompat version.  However, I am unsure as to how to fix this error, i.e. get all my dependencies on the same version.

I was wondering if there is a quick fix to do this? And, if not, what are the steps to making sure that they are all on the correct/same version?

**build.gradle (Module: app)**

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.benchalmers.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.6.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.6.1'
}
```

**This is the error that is being given to me:**

> All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version
>   specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found
>   versions 27.0.2, 26.1.0. Examples include
>   com.android.support:support-compat:27.0.2 and
>   com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:26.1.0 less... (⌘F1) 
>   There are some combinations of libraries, or tools and libraries, that
>   are incompatible, or can lead to bugs. One such incompatibility is
>   compiling with a version of the Android support libraries that is not
>   the latest version (or in particular, a version lower than your
>   targetSdkVersion.)

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Run `gradlew dependencies` from Terminal. What libraries are depending on version 27.0.2 of any of the support libraries?

Answer (score 0):

Update your dependencies like so:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.6.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.6.1'
}
```

Like the error message says: There's a conflicting version of Support Libraries found in your project. What you need to do to "fix" it is then make sure your Support Library version is the same (and preferably latest available).

In order to ease this process going forward, you could also make your code look like this:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    def supportLibraryVersion = "27.0.2"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:$supportLibraryVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:design:$supportLibraryVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:$supportLibraryVersion"
    compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$supportLibraryVersion"
    compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$supportLibraryVersion"

    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'

    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'

    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.6.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.6.1'
}
```

---

Also, as suggested by Michael Dodd, in order to use Support Library version 27.0.2, you'd need to bump your `compileSdkVersion` too:

```
android {
    ...
    compileSdkVersion 27
    ...
}
```

Comment: OP would also need to increase `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` to 27 in this case.